# HTML5 Live Audio Streaming "Windows Media Player"

Tags: html, media-player, audio-streaming, html5-audio

Some one knows if is possible to create an Audio Player for Windows Media Player using HTML5? I would like to play a live Radio streaming like this url: http://streaming.crwarpaths1.info:8000/globo

Best, Flavio

Comment: Which do you want... HTML5 or Windows Media Player?  They are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the stream you linked is using icecast. check out their website to find out how to get a stream running. [icecast.org](http://icecast.org/)